# Display Blank array in console

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using multi dimension array to store data. It working but when we print it in console it show blank array and under it its showing two array, it should be show only one array inside.
It should look like this.

```
ar['outbound']['Meal']="111,121"
```

and its look in console like this
[image]

It is printing undefined also and one more thing

how to remove "," from the last

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xuq3R/)

**Code**

```
var ar = [];
    ar['Outbound'] = [];
    ar['Inbound'] = [];
    var ch="";
    var sr= [];
    sr['Meal']= [];
    sr['Lounge']= [];   
    $('a').click(function(){
     ch = $(this).parent().find('.no').text();
     var boundType= $(this).parent().find('.bound').text();  
    ar[boundType][$(this).parent().find('.service').text()] +=($(this).parent().find('.no').text()) + ","; console.log(ar)
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid "undefined" you have to set a default value to your array items:

```
if (!ar[boundType][service]) {
    ar[boundType][service] = '';
}
```

And it's better to add ',' before adding a new value:

```
if (ar[boundType][service].length > 0) {
    ar[boundType][service] += ',';
}
```

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AVU54/1/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
ar[boundType][$(this).parent().find('.service').text()] +=($(this).parent().find('.no').text()) + ",";
```

Replace that with:

```
var temp = $(this).parent().find('.service').text();
ar[boundType][temp] = (ar[boundType][temp] + "," || '') + ($(this).parent().find('.no').text());
```

This checks if the variable exists.

Also, arrays can't have strings as indexes. Use objects, instead:

```
var ar = {};
ar['Outbound'] = {};
ar['Inbound'] = {};
// etc...
```